# React Navigation nested nav goBack()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

This is what I have for the nested nav:

```
//current screen = Stack1, screen1
navigation.navigate("Stack2", { screen: "Screen4", initial: false, })
```

I am navigating to a nested screen. (the 4th screen in a different stack).

Is it possible to have the back action from that 4th screen go back through all screens before it in Stack2 on goBack()?

Aka:

Stack1, screen1 > Stack2, screen4

goBack() from screen 4 > Stack2, screen3

etc.

Ideally I want to reset the state of the whole nav to be Stack2, screen4

Comment: I am interested in. this as well.  I am using it in react native and it seems like if a screen from stack 2 is loaded it can go back to that, but if it is not loaded, then it will go back to stack1>screen1